# Swift Mac App: Speeding up execution with dispatch queue

Tags: swift, macos, sqlite, dispatch-async

I'm a swift newbie and I'm working on a Swift Mac App as a demo project.The app stores stock symbols in a sqlite table, fetches the stock price, calculates value and then finally displays the results in a table view.
I'm looking for ways to improve execution speed when fetching data to populate my table view. So I used Dispatch Queue as shown below. The problem is that the
Stock Price and Stock Value columns (calculated in the async closure) are always empty. What am i doing wrong? The function getStocksData returns a NSMutableArray which is the datasource for my table view

```
func getStocksData() -> NSMutableArray {
        sharedInstance.database!.open()
        let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("select stock_id,symbol,company,qty from stocks ", withArgumentsIn: [])

        let stocksDBRowsArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        if (resultSet != nil) {
            while resultSet.next() {
                    let stockInfo : StockInfo = StockInfo()
                    stockInfo.StockID = resultSet.string(forColumn: "stock_id")!
                    stockInfo.Symbol = resultSet.string(forColumn: "symbol")!
                    stockInfo.StockCompany = resultSet.string(forColumn: "company")!
                    stockInfo.Qty = resultSet.string(forColumn: "qty")!
                    //create queue with unique label to fetch stock price
                    let queue=DispatchQueue(label:stockInfo.Symbol)
                    queue.async {

                        //code to fetch stock price goes here
                        .....

                        stockInfo.StockPrice=stockPrice
                        stockInfo.StockValue=stockPrice*stockInfo.Qty



                    }
                stocksDBRowsArray.add(stockInfo)
            }
        }
        sharedInstance.database!.close()
        return stocksDBRowsArray
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

When your getStocksData() method returns, the StockInfo values may, or may not yet be filled with fetched values. StockInfo values *eventually* get filled, at some *undefined* point in time, in an *undefined* application thread.

That's what the provided code snippet does. Of course this is not what you want, but what you want is not very clear either.

The documentation for Swift's Dispatch library is very terse, and won't help you much understand what is happening. I instead suggest that you study the documentation for [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async), which is the C equivalent of the Swift `DispatchQueue.async`. It is documented with much more details, and you'll read this key sentence:

> Calls to this function always return immediately after the block has been submitted and never wait for the block to be invoked.

Generally don't hesitate switching to the Objective-C documentation when the Swift documentation is lacking. Mastering some Swift technologies sometimes requires this little inconvenience. You'll learn a great deal of information there.

Comment: BTW, FMDatabase is dangerous to use in a multi-threaded context. You should use FMDatabaseQueue instead.